What is the point of "what is the point?" argument in re determinism?
One argument/perspective that I don't understand with regard to determinism goes like this:
"If determinism obtains then there's no point in arguing about determinism or anything else"
Presumably this is because ... we will believe what we believe and that belief is not a personal decision, that being the main thrust of determinism. I can't think of any other interpretation of the statement supra. Perhaps it's clearer to other folks. Would appreciate some clarificatory prose/verse in this regard.

"A recurring argument to the effect that determinism, naturalism, or both are self-referentially incoherent... presented by Arthur Lovejoy, A.E. Taylor, Kurt Gödel, C.S. Lewis, Norman Malcolm, Karl Popper, J.R. Lucas, William Hasker, Thomas Nagel, Alvin Plantinga, and others" Slagle, Epistemological Skyhook. But the argument is more subtle, deterministic acquisition of beliefs arguably undermines their connection to the truth. As for "the point" version - why argue if the result is predetermined - it is just a value judgment, soundness does not apply.

This kind of argument is always self contradictory, as it encompasses a non deterministic, or libertarian free will based, view of our decision process. If determinism is true, which is the hypothesis the argument is making and not dependent on reality or our opinion, wether something is pointless is irrelevant: we're going to do it wether it's pointless or not. It's like arguing that it's pointless for methane and oxygen to turn into water because they don't have a choice in the matter.

"Is the argument sound?" Makes this question far to broad for this site, and invites useless repetition if existing answers.

@Conifold -- It seems to me that, unfortunately, Slagle mostly gives strawman arguments -- which is exactly why scientists grow impatient with philosophers... (or simply ignore and dismiss them).

I am tempted to reply with "Mu."

Could someone please edit the sentence "If determinism obtains" or explain what this means? Is it supposed to be interpreted as "if determinism is true"?

@BuckThorn, yes. I'm not that well-versed in philosophical terminology, but it seems a stock expression.

Ok, thanks, I was unfamiliar with this (odd for the unversed) usage. A search revealed this: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8116/what-does-obtain-mean-in-philosophy-jargon


Who made this argument? Does it have a name?

Both proponents of libertarian free will as well as compatibilist would reference to that line of thought, but it has no name. Here is a quote from Eccles and Popper 1977 in "Brain and self":

That we have free will is a fact of experience. Furthermore, I state emphatically that to deny free will is neither a rational nor a logical act. This denial either presupposes free will for the deliberately chosen response in making that denial, which is a contradiction, or else it is merely the automatic response of a nervous system built by genetic coding and molded by conditioning.

But other quotes are likely to exist, in particular compatibilist responses to the libertarian view proposed in the above quote.

Is the argument sound?

In philosophy of mind there is no consensus, even if modern mainstream tends towards compatibilism. Indicating that philosophers don't strongly mind. It also seems more like a battlecry than an argument, as the question "is there a point" does not suggest falsehood, only absurdity (but life could be absurd).
Please see any of the 100s of questions on mind determinism, free will and compatibilism for details on this. Or ask specifically about the views of any single philosopher about it.
In general, evolution can be seen as the ultimate compatibility response. Fully deterministic computer simulations can show a convergence of genetic algorithms to "truth" as in "whatever solves the problem" provided there is a feedback loop. So the deterministic nature of algorithms does not prevent eventual convergence to truth, and reasoning and argument could be the evolutionary vehicle that still would work when deterministic.





You think Determinism is real
You think Free will is real




Determinism being real
You don't have free will
You think you have free will, but don't


Free Will being real
You have free will, but deny it
You have free will



So if you are a deterministic part of the universe (not just live in a deterministic world), then you don't have free will and no amount of arguing about it is going to change that in any meaningful way. So in that sense it IS pointless, because your perception of the fact doesn't change the fact and your discussion could only change your perception. So no matter how you went out of that you wouldn't have moved the needle of reality even the tiniest of fractions at most you would have changed yourself.
That being said, it's also pointless to claim that it's pointless, because the universe for some strange reason has configured itself in such a way that you were determined to do that anyway... Yet arguing that it's pointless might make you stop, so it's slightly less pointless than having that discussion given that at least theoretically someone with that goal could accomplish their goal.
While if you have free will you'd have the opposite problem. In that you could argue all day long, but all that this would express is your will to argue, you'd still have it. You could awkwardly deny it and dive into insanity, but that wouldn't really rid yourself of your free will to reject your free will or to disguise it as just "A" will. So as to pretend you're just acting upon an impules rather than having chosen that impulse yourself.
So again it's pointless because you wouldn't change reality and in that case probably not even your own perception of it (not an expert on how insanity would warp your felt reality in that regard though), just the way you act about that.
And if you have free will and acknowledge that you have free will, then you'd have free will and that's basically it. Wouldn't really change much either as you apparently still life in a largely deterministic world, that determines a huge part of your daily business, but at least you'd have some spare time to your creativity or be dreaded by your inability to make use of that.
So if your objective is to cross the horizontal lines then likely no amount of arguing is going to accomplish that and the discussions about it are thus pointless.
If you want to experience what it is like to cross one of the vertacle lines in the table, then arguing is also pointless because pretending to is somewhat of a you thing and you ultimately can't actually accomplish it.
Also while you could go from having free will to wanting to not have free will. I'm not so sure you could go from the absence of free will to the desire to have free will at least as an intrinsic will as that would be the thing that you wish for, wouldn't it? Also why would you want to fool yourself in the first place.
So the more likely positions of a person are to either believe they have no free will because free will doesn't exist or to believe free will because free will exists. So the point of any of these discussions would just be about convincing another person that they are on the complementary diagonal (will/det. or det/will) and to change towards a more matching position.
But if they actually believe in where they place themselves than they would also believe that such a change is impossible and thus not do it as that would just be awkward or not possible to begin with.
So there are a lot of possible interpretations of that that actually would render these conversations pointless. Now whether it is sound would require to know the answer...

+1 For a self-consciously pointless attempt to deter determinists and libertarians from trying to move out of their predetermined slots :)

Interesting! Thank you,

Determinism does not exclude free will except under theistic formulations of the universe.

@JackAidley How so? Like determinism argues that everything can be described as cause and effect relations where every cause has exactly 1 effect. While free will... well there are plenty of definitions of free will, but someone in there you kinda have some degree of freedom, while determinism would leave none of that as everything was already decided by the initial conditions. Now there are people who like to carve their will into an unconsequential subset and/or render it an illusion, but that feels like cheating. Or if there actually is a degree of freedom that would introduce indeterminism

@haxor789 Far too long a discussion for a comment.

This conflates determinism with some form of "fate", or suggests that we're non-deterministic beings bound by a deterministic world.
Fate might suggest that you're always going to end with a particular result, so it doesn't matter what you do, but this is an incorrect representation of determinism.
Let's consider a basic calculator. Most people would agree that's something which deterministically takes some input and produces some output. But it's clearly the case that giving it different input produces different output. 2+2 is 4, but 3*3 is 9.
Following the analogy, it's trivially the case that humans, when presented with different data and arguments, end up with different conclusions. We also have direct evidence of this happening, of people changing their mind in response to what's presented to them (even if this doesn't happen as often as we'd maybe like, for a range of reasons such as cognitive biases).
So there would be "the point" in arguing about things.
Is there a point to trying to choose under determinism?
If determinism is true, it would be the case that you can't "choose" to try to change anyone's mind about anything - you'd either do it or you wouldn't do it.
But to realise that you can't choose this, and then to use this information to act in one way or the other, is a self-undermining line of reasoning. This reasoning presumes that you're able to choose whether to be subject to determinism, that you can notice determinism and then either submit or not. But the issue is that this process itself would be deterministic. You can't use whether determinism is true to shirk responsibility of making decisions. It's an invalid factor of consideration, and you'd be "choosing" (whether deterministically or not) to use this factor, instead of, say, considering how your actions would affect others. It's a bad excuse for someone to be a bad person or to give in to hopelessness.
* This doesn't "presuppose free will" or make determinism self-defeating, like others might say. It's merely a matter of fact that reasoning based on the foundation of one's reasoning is often invalid (particularly to conclude that one cannot reason) due to circularity. It would be similarly invalid to say "My reasoning is random, so I have no ability to influence my choices, so I can't decide to not go out and stab some people".
But you can absolutely use whether determinism is true to determine how to best act with respect to others or one's future self, e.g. you know your future self will be unable to resist eating snacks you have in your house, so your present self decides to not have snacks in the house as a result. This supposes some level of determinism is true (regardless of whether determinism is true more broadly), and it's a line of reasoning that most people use on a daily basis.
See also: What are the implications of accepting that we don't have free will?
Does determinism undermine its connection to truth?

"deterministic acquisition of beliefs arguably undermines their connection to the truth"

Does the calculator's deterministic acquisition of a result undermine its connection to the truth? Would we trust a calculator more if 2+2 doesn't necessarily give 4, but could instead give any number of results?
The very reason that we trust it is because it's deterministic. It actually seems to be non-determinism (particularly libertarian free will) which has this problem, because that means being able to end up with any number of results given the same input, which makes it questionable to say the result corresponds to a true thing in reality.
Quantum randomness?
Note: The possible fundamental randomness of particles due to quantum effects would mean determinism isn't true. But what I said above still applies. Randomness doesn't help get you to a meaningful concept of free will. To the point that things are random, there wouldn't be any point in trying to affect them... because they're random. So we can try to determine which things are deterministic, and try to affect those, while accepting that random (or things we can't accurately predict at this point in time) things are just things we need to accept.

+1 Good point about the calculator. It's weird that someone with any kind of philosophical training could believe the quoted statement.

When I think about what a true determinist believer would feel and do, all I can imagine is them going "Aaaaaaahh!" like someone thrown from an airplane without a parachute. I don't see many people doing that, so I surmise that there are few true determinist believers :-)

@ScottRowe That's exactly what I see them doing, though. They yell unarticulated sounds like "Aaaaaaaahh". It's just that they believe their yell is true.

@Olivier5 oh well, they just can't help themselves. They would be the first to admit it.

@ScottRowe Some counterexamples for your consideration: (a) Man cannot do — Gurdjieff (b) The events of your life are not in your hand; all that's in your hands is to inquire into your self and to know yourself — Ramana

Simply put, if we live in a strictly deterministic world then any speech we make has the same valence as the sounds that boulders make when they roll down a hill. Speech would merely be a series of sounds made by the vocal apparatus in response to a cascade of neuro-electrical impulses that is itself strictly deterministic. The pretext that we are 'making an argument' or 'trying to convince someone' is entirely vapid, because we can't choose  to try to convince someone, and no one can choose to be convinced. Of course, no one can choose not to make the argument either, so the whole exercise is futile.
It's like two people at the crest of a rollercoaster arguing about whether gravity exists. It doesn't matter how passionate they are, the outcome isn't going to change.
The "What's the point?" approach is a type of reductio ad absurdum (though not a strongly formulated one), asserting something like: "If what you say is true, then what you say is utterly void and meaningless". It's supposed to make people reflect on the idea that the argument is self-defeating because people who truly believe it must also truly believe that they have no capacity to make arguments. But not too many people think it through that way.

I have to agree. Gracias. Excellent points.

I think the argument that determinism steals science's and philosophy's thunder is sound and correct, when such determinism is conceived as reductionist, i.e. if our ideas are seen as meaningless noise made by the brain machinery. In this case of course, the whole of science and philosophy would be meaningless noise. A reductionist determinist should really shut up, if he could, because by his own account he's only making noise.
But things are different if determinism works in non-reductionist ways, i.e. if it takes into account the power of ideas within its causality mechanisms.^ In this compatibilist view, ideas can be both predetermined and meaningful. So a compatibilist determinist has no reason to shut up. His ideas have status in his own world view.
^ by that i mean that, simply put, ideas are considered causal. They have causes and consequences in the world. IOW, thoughts are necessary for certain outcomes, and a brain unable to create thoughts, like the brain of a p-zombie, would be a dysfunctional brain, aka unable to fulfill its function, which is to produce thoughts, which will then do their thing (cause whatever they cause).

This seems strangely hostile.  And FYI, to a reductionist determinist, you're also "only making noise".  I dont see that as a valid reason to shut down discourse.  "It makes us question the strength of reasoning in general" is not a reason to outright deny something. It seems like that's driven more by fear or distaste of the theory, not any logical reason to reject it.

@JMac I'm just being logical here. So to the degree that I am hostile, it's hostility  towards logical contradictions. Philosophers who question the strength of reasoning in general are sawing the branch on which they sit.

I don't follow how it's a "logical contradiction".  Sure, if reductionist determinism is correct, it does mean that reason and logic lose value; but reality will be whatever reality is.  Just because a world where reason and logic dont apply is inconvenient or uncomfortable, that doesnt actually do anything to prove that it isnt the case.

@JMac In a world "where reason and logic dont apply", one cannot assert confidently that "reality will be whatever reality is", because that is actually one instance of applying logic. In fact one cannot confidently assert anything, not even that logic and reason don't apply.

Logic and reason dont logically or reasonably conclude that logic and reason are real.  You cant use logic and reason to assert logic and reason must exist, that's a circular arguement, which is neither logical or reasonable.  "If logic and reason dont exist, logic and reason dont exist" is just a tautology, it doesnt allow you to follow with "therefore logic and reason exist".

@JMac What I am saying, is that logic and reason are not optional in science or philosophy but essential to the project. Once you jettisoned reason, you are not doing science or philosophy anymore. Which is fine, but you're doing something else than the pursuit of knowledge through reason.

Yet reason doesn't inherently allow you to rule out a world where logic and reason are not actually real.  You need a non-circular reason to deny it, or else your assumption that reason must exist is actually poisoning your pursuit of knowledge by basing it on unfounded assumptions.

This reminds me of a presuppositionalist argument where you just go "logic and reason actually come from God, so you can't use reason to prove God doesn't exist".

Reductionism and compatibilism aren't mutually exclusive. To a large degree, compatibilism and incompatibilism just differ on how they define "free will". I have no idea what "the power of ideas within its causality mechanisms" means. Reductionism has ideas reducing to physical things that have causal interactions, which sounds like it meets the aforementioned criteria as well.

@JMac I have no problem with assuming that reason and logic work, although it cannot be proven of course, since any such proof would rely on reason and logic. I just commit to this belief, that's all. These are among the very few tools we have, so we might as well try them out, the way I see it.

@Olivier5 I just think it's strange to be so dismissive of the alternatives.  It's important to remember that you are assuming logic and reason exist in the first place; and taking them as a brute fact meant to dismantle anything that challenges their actual existence is circular.  Such an approach is equally as flawed as saying logic/reason cant exist, and using logic and reason to justify it.

@NotThatGuy By "including the power of ideas in their causality mechanisms", I mean that, simply put, ideas are causal. They have causes and consequences in the world. IOW, thoughts are necessary for certain outcomes, and a brain unable to create thoughts, like the brain of a p-zombie, would be a dysfunctional brain, aka unable to fulfill its function, which is to produce thoughts, which will then do their thing (cause whatever they cause).

@JMac I agree that "It's important to remember that I am assuming logic and reason exist in the first place". But the point is that anyone who participates in a philosophical discussion does do the same, otherwise they wouldn't engage in the first place.
